# Alpha, Transparency, Blender, Sony Vegas, Workflow, & solutions

Tags: transparency, workflow

I rendered a video in blender as ffmpeg qt mov. File w xlpha transparency.

To make the video file size more manageable, I went with another render of the same file; in Sony Vegas. So I added the file, went to properties and went with straight unmatted… Then Rendered as mp4 w alpha to use I n blender.

The issue I’m having is… Alpha doesn’t work at all… In blender but it’s working in Sony Vegas.

My plan is to bring this video back into blender as an mp4 or any other file type that can utilize transparency, and use a “hold out” behind the video’s plane, so that I may be able to have alpha show through the video plane; on the final render.

I hope this explains a lot without me having to reveal what I’m working on. Please help.